# How to resolve Fxcop installation error in VS2015 with project authored in MSBuild 2010 format?

Tags: xml-namespaces

The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

Can anyone suggest any other fix?

I am trying to install Fxcop package through nuget package manager in vs2015 with project in 2010
Even though the XML namespace of the project is set to msbuild 2003 still getting the same error